# Dynamic numpy reshape of a web-scraped table in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having trouble getting a usable data frame from scraping a website. I know I need to turn my list into a list of lists, and that's easy to do with a static data frame. But here's the rub: **my scraped data changes daily**, and I want to automate the data frame creation. First, I scrape the data:

```
### Libraries/packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


### Function 1
def strava_page():

    urllist = ['https://www.strava.com/login',
               'https://www.strava.com/clubs/roosevelt-island-dc-parkrun']

    return urllist

### Function 2
def strava_login(urllist):

    # navigate to page
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"/Users/user/Documents/chromedriver")
    driver.get(urllist[1])

    # last week's leaderboard
    last_week = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.view > div.page.container > div:nth-child(4) > div.spans11 > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span')
    last_week.click()

    # getting rows from leaderboard
    table_rows = []
    myrow = []
    totalrows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaderboard']/table/tbody//tr"))
    print("[Number of Rows in Leaderboard]:", totalrows)

    # gets individual rows, and puts each one into its own list
    for i in range(totalrows):
        myrow.clear()
        for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaderboard']/table/tbody//tr["+str(i+1)+"]/td"):
            myrow.append(items.text)
        table_rows.append(myrow)
        print(myrow)

    driver.close()

    # myrow variable is a list
    print(type(myrow))

    # column names
    my_columns = ['Rank', 'Athlete', 'Distance', 'Runs', 'Longest', 'Avg. Pace', 'Elev. Gain']


    # PROBLEM AREA *************
    new_table = pd.DataFrame(np.array(myrow).reshape(1, 7), columns = my_columns)

    return new_table

### Calling functions
one = strava_page()
two = strava_login(one)
two
```

I keep getting `cannot reshape data size` errors. I know the numpy reshape is the correct way to go. But I cannot get the `myrow` output into a full frame - i.e. it only returns the last row of that frame:

[image]

When I want EVERY row in the table from the Strava webpage. How do I dynamically get every row into a table (with day-to-day variation of number of rows), and not have to set the `.reshape()` by hand every time I run the script?

For reference, here's a screenshot of the table. There are 7 columns, and number of rows should reflect the number of rows in the table, even the number of rows change daily:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific on which line do you get the error

Comment: The `new_table = pd.DataFrame(np.array(myrow).reshape(1, 7), columns = my_columns)` line - it only puts one row into a dataframe, where I need all the rows in the table

Comment: I assume it's this: `reshape(1, 7)`.  You'll get errors if the array doesn't have 7 elements.  You can substitute other values, possibly derived from `np.array(myrow).shape`.  You can also use `reshape(-1,7)` or `reshape(1,-1)`.

Comment: Will try that. But I think my problem is really how to get all N rows into the dataframe, instead of the just the last one, which it presently does

Comment: Are you saving the rows in the iteration?  Or just using the last row?

Comment: It's appended in there - does that not save it adequately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple fix, all it took was for me to ignore work for a bit, and play around with `numpy` outside of the loop:

```
new_table = np.array(myrow).reshape(-1, 7)
previous_week = pd.DataFrame(new_table, columns = my_columns)
```

I got rid of the `myrow.clear()`, and returned `previous_week`. Worked like a charm, after I discovered the `-1` method in `np.reshape()`.